# create a mock that doesn't implement all the methods of the original service

Tags: angular, typescript

Suppose I have an OriginalService with multiple methods

```
class OriginalService {

  method1() { }
  method2() { }
  method3() { }
.. 
}
```

and I want to create a mock of `OriginalService` that will only be used with `method1`.

If I write the following, typescript will tell me that methods are missing on `mockService`

```
let mockService: OriginalService;
mockService = {
  method1() {
  }
```

How can I declare `mockService` as `OriginalService` without having to write all the properties of `OriginalService` ?

Answer (score 0):

Extend `OriginalService` class:

```
class MockService extends OriginalService {
   method1() {
      // let's override this method!
  }
}

let mockService = new MockService();
this.mockService.method1();
```

Take a look at this documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Hope I helped you! God luck and Good coding!

Comment: that's no good because I'll be instantiating the real service expect for the overident method. I want to instantiate a mock with method1 and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to go the other way around and define an interface that only includes the methods you are going to mock.

```
interface Service {
    method1();
}

let realService: Service;
let mockService: Service;

realService = new RealService();
mockService = {
    method1() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then, when you call that particular method, you only need to know that it fits the interface.

```
function test(svc: Service) {
    svc.method1();
}
```

You could even declare multiple interfaces, one for each mock, and the real service could implement them all.